# Sum of prime numbers below 2,000,000 giving wrong result

Tags: c++, primes

I have to sum all prime numbers below 2,000,000 but my code is giving the wrong result(1,179,908,154 right is 142,913,828,922), since it's working perfectly with lower values I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){ 
    unsigned int j, i=2,ans=2, interval=2000000;

    while(i<=interval){
        i++;
        j=2;

        while(i!=j){            
            if(i % j != 0)
                j++;
            else{
                i++; j=2;}
        }

        if (i>=interval)
            break;

        cout << i<< endl;
        ans+=i;
    }

    cout << ans;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by telling us at what value problem begins.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP has not apparently attempted to solve it.

Comment: maybe the sum doesn't fit into an int? Are you sure you don't overflow?

Comment: If 1,179,908,154 is wrong, then please tell us what's the proper answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are declaring `ans` as `unsigned int`, on most machines today, that's 32-bit, which can represent numbers from `0` to `4294967295`, but the sum of all prime numbers under two million is definitely way over `4294967295`, try use `unsigned long long` instead.

By the way, the algorithm you used is very inefficient, you may consider [The sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes):

Comment: @Zeor137 you should accept the answer when it's solved